# jqgrid not getting populated with data

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to get a jqgrid populated with JSON data returned from the server.

Below is my jqgrid configuration code -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({
  jsonReader : {
       repeatitems: false,
       id: "0"
  },
     url:'/data/scans',
     datatype:'json',
     colNames:['Scan ID','Scanned Machine', 'Begin Time', 'End Time'],
     colModel:[
      {name:'scanId',index:'scanId', width:100, jsonmap:"scanId"},
      {name:'scannedMachine',index:'scannedMachine', width:150, jsonmap:"scannedMachine"},
      {name:'beginTime',index:'beginTime', width:180,jsonmap:"beginTime"},
      {name:'endTime',index:'endTime', width:180,jsonmap:"scanId"}   
     ],
     rowNum:10,
     rowList:[10,20,30],
     pager: '#pager4',
     sortname: 'scanId',
     viewrecords: true,
     sortorder: "desc",
     caption:"JSON Example"
 });
 jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager4',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

The JSON data returned from server looks like this -

```
{ total: '1',
page: '1',
records: '2',
rows:[
{scanId:"123", scannedMachine:"Axbhad", beginTime:"Fri Apr 13 13:02:52 IST 2018", endTime:"Fri Apr 13 13:02:52 IST 2018"},
{scanId:"123", scannedMachine:"Axbhad", beginTime:"Fri Apr 13 13:02:52 IST 2018", endTime:"Fri Apr 13 13:02:52 IST 2018"}]}
```

but the html page is always displaying an empty grid like this - 
[image]

Can someone please point out what is it that I am not doing correct.

Comment: Please write *always*, which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). In any way, `id: "0"` property in `jsonReader` option is wrong. You should use `id: "scanId"` probably. It's important in the case that you use **unique** values of `scanId`. The test data contains two items with *the same* `scanId`, which will be wrong. Finally, you should remove unneeded `index` and `jsonmap` from `colModel`

Comment: I'd strictly recommend you to change the format of data in `beginTime` and `endTime` columns. The best way would be the usage of language independent ISO date format (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)). One can still use `formatter: "date"` in the columns to display the date in another format for the users. See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data), [here](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/j3hj8rsw/) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter) for more details.

Comment: @Oleg The version I am using is _free jqGrid  4.6.0_ hosted at [http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js)

Comment: Did as you advised. `id="scanId"`, unique values for `scanId` for two test data items, removed `index` and `jasonmap` from `colModel` and used `formatter: "date"` still same result.

Comment: I'm not sure which errors you have. The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/bxo5zvyv/ uses free jqGrid 4.15.4 and your code and data loaded from JSFiddle. I added only `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` option to use Font Awesome instead of old jQuery UI icons (see [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data)). The same code using retro version 4.6 works too. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/uqwwyecL/. By the way `jsonmap:"scanId"` is wrong in the column `name:'endTime'` (copy error???)

Comment: Yeah that was a copy error. By the way I have got it working. All I did is correctly punctuated the JSON string. Now it looks like this - `{ "total": "1",
"page": "1",
"records": "2",
"rows":[
{"scanId":"123", "scannedMachine":"Axbhad", "beginTime":"Fri Apr 13 17:17:30 IST 2018", "endTime":"Fri Apr 13 17:17:30 IST 2018"},
{"scanId":"124", "scannedMachine":"Axbhad", "beginTime":"Fri Apr 13 17:17:30 IST 2018", "endTime":"Fri Apr 13 17:17:30 IST 2018"}]}`. Thanks for taking time to look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got it working. All I did is correctly punctuated the JSON string. 
Now it looks like this -

```
{ "total": "1", "page": "1", "records": "2", "rows":[ {"scanId":"123", "scannedMachine":"Axbhad", "beginTime":"Fri Apr 13 17:17:30 IST 2018", "endTime":"Fri Apr 13 17:17:30 IST 2018"}, {"scanId":"124", "scannedMachine":"Axbhad", "beginTime":"Fri Apr 13 17:17:30 IST 2018", "endTime":"Fri Apr 13 17:17:30 IST 2018"}]}.
```

To avoid making such silly mistake, I have used GSON libabry as below -

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new Gson().toJson(this);
}
```